# Setting Slider value in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set a Slider value through C# code.

I have a `Main.scene` which includes a slider called Slider.
The main camera has a game manager script attached to it.

The slider is not Interactable (so I can display the value but the user can't change it).

I defined a variable:

```
[SerializeField] private Slider sliderObj;
```

and put my slider in the inspector in this field
I have a float `s` variable that I want to reflect in the slider:

```
s = player1Time / (player1Time + player2Time) * 100.0f;
```

but when I write:

```
sliderObj.value = s;
```

I see this error:

> 'Slider' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'Slider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]

any ideas?

Here is the entire script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameManager instance = null;  //this is to create a singleton => only one instance of this script running in memory
                                                //so we only have one Game Manager running on memory
    private int activePlayer = 1; //1 = down position 2 = up position
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject playerObj;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text timer1Text;   //player1 timer text
    [SerializeField]
    private Text timer2Text;   //player2 timer text
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject startBtn;
    [SerializeField]
    private Texture stopTexture;
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider sliderObj;
    private Slider sli;
    public float sli_val;
    private RawImage img;

    private float startTime;

    private bool player1Active = true;
    private static float player1Time;
    private static float lastP1Time;
    private static float player2Time;
    private static float lastP2Time;
    private bool gameOver = false;
    private bool gameStarted = false;
    private bool gameFinished = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        { //check if an instance of Game Manager is created
            instance = this;    //if not create one
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);    //if already exists destroy the new one trying to be created
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);  //Unity function allows a game object to persist between scenes
    }

    public bool GameStarted
    {
        get { return gameStarted; }
    }

    public bool GameOver
    {
        get { return gameOver; }
    }
    public void StartGame()
    {

        if (!gameStarted)
        {
            gameStarted = true;
            //startTime = Time.time;
            //player1Time = startTime;
            player1Active = true;
            //select start button
            img = (RawImage)startBtn.GetComponent<RawImage>();
            //replace it with stop button
            img.texture = (Texture)stopTexture;
        }
        else
        {
            gameStarted = false;
            gameOver = true;
        }

        Debug.Log("StartGame");
    }
    public void ChangePlayer()
    {
        float ty = 0f;
        int smileyRotate = 180;
        int sliderRotate = 180;

        Quaternion smileyRotation = playerObj.transform.localRotation;

        ty = playerObj.transform.position.y * -1;

        if (activePlayer == 1)
        {
            player1Active = false;
            activePlayer = 2;
            smileyRotate = 180;
        }
        else
        {
            player1Active = true;
            activePlayer = 1;
            smileyRotate = 0;
        }
        playerObj.transform.position = new Vector2(playerObj.transform.position.x, ty);
        smileyRotation.x = smileyRotate;
        playerObj.transform.localRotation = smileyRotation;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    private string FormatTime(float pt)
    {
        string hours, minutes, seconds, shaon;

        hours = ((int)pt / 3600).ToString("00");
        minutes = ((int)pt / 60).ToString("00");
        seconds = (pt % 60).ToString("00");
        if ((pt / 3600) > 1)
        {
            shaon = string.Format("{0:D1}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hours, minutes, seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            shaon = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", minutes, seconds);
        }

        return shaon;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        float s;
        GameObject sl1 = GameObject.Find("Slider");

        if (GameStarted)
        {
            string zman;
            if (player1Active)
            {
                player1Time += Time.deltaTime;  //if player 1 active update his time
                zman = FormatTime(player1Time);
                timer1Text.text = zman;
                //Debug.Log("player2Time: : "+ player2Time);
            }
            else
            {
                player2Time += Time.deltaTime;  //if player 2 active update his time
                zman = FormatTime(player2Time);
                timer2Text.text = zman;
                Debug.Log("player1Time: : " + player1Time);
            }

            s = player1Time / (player1Time + player2Time) * 100.0f;
            //sliderObj.GetComponent<Slider>;
            //sliderObj.=0.5f;
            sli = GameObject.Find("Slider").GetComponent<Slider>();
            sli.value = s;
            sliderObj.value = s;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace ?

Comment: yes, I did imported UnityEngine.UI

Comment: Did you confirm that the sliderObj is a Unity slider and not a type from another namespace?

Comment: This is the sliderObj declaration:  [SerializeField] private Slider sliderObj;    in the game manager script and I try to use this variable in the same script in the Update function

Comment: Have you tried UnityEngine.UI.Slider instead of just Slider for the type?

Comment: What do you mean? I did the slider like this: right click on the Canvas > UI > Slider  then in my game manager I declared the [SerializeField] private Slider sliderObj; I dragged the Slider to the variable in the inspector. And in the same script in the Update function I've tried to put a value to the sliderObj so it will be shown in my GUI. That's it I didn't use getcomponent or other commands (I've tried it didn't help)

Comment: Can you post your entire script?

Comment: Do you possibly have a separate C# script named "Slider" ?

Comment: Yes I do have a script called Slider, but I don't have any code in it. I thought that I may need it to update the value, but after looking in the internet I thought that updating the value through the game manager would make sense more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130724/discussion-between-bpgeck-and-daniel-ben-shabtay).

Comment: You are **not** suppose to have a script called `Slider` because there is a Unity API with that name. If you do and then try to use functions or variables from Unity's Slider class, you will run into big problems This is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thanks for all your help.
Specially to bpgeck that chat with me and help me a  lot.
Also Programmer was correct.
The main problem I had was the fatal error of calling the script attached to my slider Slider (I am still a noob, but learning)
I deleted that script and created a new one called Slider Percentage, in it I use the update function to change the value of the slider:

```
GameObject temp;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    temp = GameObject.Find("Slider");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    temp.GetComponent<Slider>().value = GameManager.instance.GetPercentage;
}
```

The percentage value is still being calculated in the GameManager, but it is displayed using this script.
Now all works!! Thanks again for all your help :-)